# Lion ate my RVM and now I can't install Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, osx-lion

I recently upgraded to Lion and everything was fine.  Even rebooted the machine a few time.  Then over the weekend, `Rails` was gone!  All of my gemsets were gone.  I swear I don't know what happened. It WAS working just fine.

After looking closer, RVM itself was gone.

So, I reinstall RVM and try to install Ruby 1.9.2 and I get this error log:

```
[2011-08-08 14:30:41]  ./configure --prefix="/Users/cbmeeks/.rvm/usr"  
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... config/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/cbmeeks/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

It appears that gcc is gone?  I'd prefer not to just start randomly reinstalling everything since all was working before.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I found this question while trying to trouble shoot installing Ruby 1.9.3 on OS 10.7.2 with XCode 4.2.1. Reinstalling didn't work, but this answer to another question did: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8032980/102401. Figured I'd post a related link here in case others ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you install Lion, you have to re-install Xcode/Developer tools.  It is available from the app store.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id448457090?mt=12

Comment: Friend of mine went through this very thing last week and installing xcode again did the trick.

Comment: Yep.  That did it.  But I swear.  I used RVM for 8+ days before this happened.  But oh well.

Comment: Note for xcode 4.3: there is no "Install XCode" app any more, just install from the App Store; install the Command Line Tools from the Downloads preferences pane; then I was able to successfully "rvm install 1.9.2" and "rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang"

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to do a full XCode install, you might want to check out this project: https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

Answer (score 4):

SUMMARY FOR STACK OVERFLOW

I was trying to install SiriProxy on a clean Lion installation on Xcode from App Store

I kept getting errors like :
The provided CC(/usr/bin/gcc) is LLVM based.

```
bash-3.2$ rvm install 1.9.3
ERROR: The provided CC(/usr/bin/gcc) is LLVM based, it is not yet fully supported by ruby and gems, please read `rvm requirements`.
```

After 2 days finally **got it working with these two lines:**

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000145/ruby-rvm-llvm-and-mysql

bash-3.2$ rvm get head
bash-3.2$ CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3 --enable-shared
```

Before that I had tried every stackoverflow article on Ruby and Lion so doing these may have done some setup that helped the above 2 steps work:

Things I tried included:

Running Install Xcode.app (I had downloaded from App Store - running this does futher installation)

Installing

```
https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/downloads may help for installing GCC.
```

Set up CC in

more /Users//.bash_profile

```
bash-3.2$ more /Users/<USERNAME>/.bash_profile 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
export CC=/usr/share/TargetConfigs/bin/gcc
```

First line came from SiriProxy install instruction
https://github.com/plamoni/SiriProxy

2nd line export CC never seemed to work. So dont add.

It had many versions each pointing
I finally used CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3 --enable-shared

Answer (score 3):

For those using xCode 4.2.X you have to add

```
export CC=gcc
```

to your ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: Note that this may bring us one step closer to the solution (unclear so far, as I have not yet solved it), but doesn't actually solve the problem. The new error message is: `ERROR: The provided CC(gcc) is LLVM based, it is not yet fully supported by ruby and gems, please read 'rvm requirements'.`

Answer (score 1):

Try running `gcc` from a terminal and see if that works?

The solution is probably to reinstall Xcode.

Comment: Ah.  Good catch.  That upsets me a little.  I used to download XCode for free.  Then PAID the $5 or whatever it was on Snow Leopard.  Now, it's free again.  Anyway, looks like I'm running version 3.x.x so I'm installing the newest version again.

Comment: @cbmeeks - the $5 was because of Apple's strange accounting practices.  Same reason that facetime was $0.99.  It has to do with them not being able to add new features without charging or something ridiculously "bean-counter" like that.  They've changed their accounting practices so that it will never happen again.  Irritating.

Comment: Fine.  Then change the accounting practice to give me a $5 credit in the app store.  lol

Answer (score 1):

latest development version (`rvm get head`) will automatically use LLVM version of GCC (`clang`) for `ruby 1.9.3-p125+`

so you need to download https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer only for older rubies.

Also be careful with mixing osx-gcc-installer with Xcode 4.2.1+ - compilation/header errors might occur.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled on the same problem. Just did:

> rvm get head
>
> rvm reload

and then got

> rvm install 1.9.3

to work!

This automatically gets p125 and compiles everything fine.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by installing the Command Line Tools in Xcode just as tardate suggested above. I had removed my old Xcode and installed the new version, but had not installed the Command Line Tools. I wanted to point this out because the tip from tardate was not easy to notice.