# Ruby, RVM, LLVM and MySQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

I'm having big trouble in configuring Ruby and MySQL on MacOSX. Just a fact, I'm new on MacOSX and Ruby On Rails.

So, first I was having problems to install mysql2 gem, after get the gem installed I was trying developer a test, and when I tried start the WEBrick got this error saying that couldn't load a MySQL lib called "libmysqlclient.18.dylib". Googlin' about the error I saw that everyone was recommending using Ruby through RVM. I installed RVM and tried install ruby 1.9.3 and get this error:

> ERROR: The provided CC(/usr/bin/gcc) is LLVM based, it is not yet fully supported by ruby and gems, please read `rvm requirements`.

I'm almost giving up learn Rails, setup a development  environment shouldn't be that painful. On Windows I got no problems.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're trying Rails at a bit of a bad time.  There's a lot of transition at the moment, as others have mentioned Xcode 4.2 was recently released and has a new compiler, also Ruby 1.9.3 came out.

I've been developing Ruby and Rails for some years now, but trying to get up and running again after installing Lion clean this week has been more problematic than in the past.

First, make sure RVM is up to date (as the issue should be fixed):

```
rvm get head
```

Then try installing like so:

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3 --enable-shared
```

**EDIT**:

Note, working through my own issues I believe the first command probably fixed the problem.  The second wouldn't have provided any benefit over:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

As on my clean install, /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 doesn't exist.

Also I wanted to add that I ended up compiling the older GCC manually for those situations where the new compiler fails.  I followed [this very informative blog post](http://caiustheory.com/install-gcc-421-apple-build-56663-with-xcode-42).

Comment: I installed the osx-gcc-installer(https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer) in one of my previous tries, maybe that must did the trick to work. So I installed Ruby and RVM, in the week I'll test to see if everything is OK.

Comment: rvm get head

CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3 --enable-shared

COMBO WORKED

Comment: Thnxs! I had to follow your "very informative blog post" and manually compile gcc

Comment: You can also install gcc with this simple installer: https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

Comment: thanks! it was troubling with different xcode versions, default installs, different ruby versions etc. but rvm get head worked! thanks!

Comment: Using gcc-4.2 and `--enable-shared` was my preferred method of installing old ruby 1.8.7 on Lion. Using `rvm install 1.8.7 --with-gcc=clang` is not fully supported, as stated elsewhere.

Comment: Just to clear up any confusion, the second command `CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3 --enable-shared` does help. `rvm get head` alone wasn't enough to fix this for me!

Comment: rvm get head then CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang

Comment: Thanks! My issue was that I didn't have a non llvm based c compiler so the link to the blog post was the part that I needed.

Comment: +1 for updating rvm, though it did blow all my gemsets away. No big seal since everything is set up using bundler.

Comment: Running 'rvm get head' then 'CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3-p362 --with-gcc=lang --enable-shared' worked.

Answer (score 48):

add `--with-gcc=clang` as a parameter:

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

Comment: I'm try to install an older version of ruby to follow along with some 3 year old examples

rvm install 1.8.6 --with-gcc=clang

worked a charm, thanks

Comment: could install 1.9.3 no problem but anything older then that, would not go through. This helped me. Thank you @team-pannous

Answer (score 3):

Did you install the latest Xcode from Mac Store?

here is a nice guide i followed to update my ruby/Rails to 1.9.2/3.0

[guide](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac)

good luck

Answer (score 2):

Part of the problem is that with Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion), Apple switched C compilers, and some things don't build well with the new (LLVM) compiler yet. See http://eddorre.com/posts/rails-ultimate-install-guide-on-os-x-lion-using-rvm-homebrew-and-pow for decent instructions (note: I haven't followed these exact instructions, but they're a pretty good summary of the things I *did* do to get Rails working on Lion).

Once you have the C compiler issue dealt with, everything else should be pretty effortless.

Bonus tip: avoid MySQL. PostgreSQL is better in nearly every respect.

Comment: Also, you don't need Pow to get started. If you want to just follow the instructions for building Ruby, {My|Postgre}SQL, and Rails, that's fine.

Comment: Followed the instructions and downloaded Ruby, after that RVM tried to install and got a error saying that is missing zlib headers, openssl and GNU development headers. 

Really, I'm coming from Windows and .NET, I having to compile the sources to simple start in a language is a little absurd to me. hehehehe

Comment: What's absurd about building from source? In the Unix world, lots of things are available as precompiled binaries, but some things aren't. What *is* absurd is that the build process is hard, but blame that on a recent compiler change and packages that haven't quite caught up yet.

Comment: Anyway, you should just be able to install the appropriate headers. It would help to see the exact error messages, though.

Comment: as i stated in my response, installing the latest version of Xcode will solve your C Compiler issues.  Did you do it?

Comment: Marnen Laibow-Koser: How I said, I'm not used to that. The install.log file: http://pastebin.com/4UjUstK9

Comment: Try Ruby 1.9.2 (or 1.9.3) instead of REE. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: Also, I've seen some info indicating that Xcode 4.2 may be problematic for building Ruby. Try 4.1.

Comment: OK, you probably just need to specify some `ARCH_FLAGS`. But before you do that, have you tried Xcode 4.1?

Comment: I need Xcode 4.2 because I'm developing iPhone apps. There's another way?

Comment: You can use the system Ruby for now (it's adequate for Rails, though it's 1.8.7), or see if anyone's got 1.9 binaries available. Or https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer might do the trick (see https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/62 ).

Comment: At this point, you might want to ask the Ruby or Rails mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Delamenko finally got it to work

SUMMARY FOR STACK OVERFLOW

I was trying to install SiriProxy on a clean Lion installation on Xcode from App Store

I kept getting errors like :
The provided CC(/usr/bin/gcc) is LLVM based.

```
bash-3.2$ rvm install 1.9.3
ERROR: The provided CC(/usr/bin/gcc) is LLVM based, it is not yet fully supported by ruby and gems, please read `rvm requirements`.
```

After 2 days finally got it working with these two lines

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000145/ruby-rvm-llvm-and-mysql

bash-3.2$ rvm get head
bash-3.2$ CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3 --enable-shared
```

Before that I had tried every stackoverflow article on Ruby and Lion so doing these may have done some setup that helped the above 2 steps work:

Things I tried included:

Running Install Xcode.app (I had downloaded from App Store - running this does futher installation)

Installing

```
https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/downloads may help for installing GCC.
```

Set up CC in

more /Users//.bash_profile

```
bash-3.2$ more /Users/<USERNAME>/.bash_profile 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
export CC=/usr/share/TargetConfigs/bin/gcc
```

First line came from SiriProxy install instruction
https://github.com/plamoni/SiriProxy

2nd line export CC never seemed to work. So dont add.

It had many versions each pointing
I finally used CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3 --enable-shared

Answer (score 0):

See [Arkku's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8032980/189804) - I tried everything here first, then did what he said and all is well.

As of Lion 10.7.3, Xcode 4.2 and Ruby 1.9.3p0 it's what works.