# how can use heroku db:push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

I have a Ruby 1.9.3p194/Rails 3.2.7 application. I want to push my local database to heroku.
I use `heroku db:push` but I get these errors:

```
Schema:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:11
Sending indexes
schema_migrat: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:02
Sending data
5 tables, 30 records
magazines:       0% |                                          | ETA:  --:--:--
Saving session to push_201301231426.dat..
!!! Caught Server Exception
HTTP CODE: 500
Taps Server Error: PGError: ERROR:  time zone displacement out of range: "2013-01-23 12:00:00.000000+5895158400"
```

Comment: see this https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps/issues/92

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check out this solved SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151571/error-when-pushing-data-to-heroku-time-zone-displacement-out-of-range)

Are you using Ruby 1.9.3-p0? Apparently switching to 1.9.2-p290 will resolve the issue.

Otherwise, check out [this Github issue.](https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps/issues/92)

Comment: Right. It's believed to be an issue with the difference between the marshalling in Ruby 1.9.3 and Ruby 1.9.2. Switching to Ruby 1.9.2 should resolve your issue, or you can follow the above links for other possible options.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that many people are experiencing. Switching versions didn't do it for me, I had to use another fix found here: [Issue on Github](https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps/issues/92)

Answer (score 0):

First I install **rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290** but I have a mac os and it has problems so you can install new ruby verion on rvm like this  **rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290 --with-gcc=clang** after you install ruby , you need to install taps , after that you can use **heroku db:push**

**1-** [Ruby, RVM, LLVM and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000145/ruby-rvm-llvm-and-mysql)

**2-** [Error when pushing data to Heroku: time zone displacement out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151571/error-when-pushing-data-to-heroku-time-zone-displacement-out-of-range/10129060#10129060)