# Can't install Ruby under Lion with RVM – GCC issues

Tags: ruby, gcc, rvm, osx-lion, xcode4.2

Most questions regarding this problem are due to missing Xcode; I have Xcode 4.2 installed.

Install attempt:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #extracted to /Users/jamie/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0 (already extracted)
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/jamie/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/jamie/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /Users/jamie/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Compiling yaml in /Users/jamie/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Installing yaml to /Users/jamie/.rvm/usr
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #configuring 
ERROR: Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml-dir=/Users/jamie/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/jamie/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/configure.log
ERROR: There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

configure.log:

```
[2011-11-07 04:32:17]  ./configure --prefix=/Users/jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml-dir=/Users/jamie/.rvm/usr 
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libyaml-dir
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/jamie/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

GCC is available:

```
gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.1~1/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.1~1/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)

ls /usr/bin | grep gcc         
gcc
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2
llvm-gcc
llvm-gcc-4.2
```

Based on config.log (posted at bottom due to size) I tried symlinking gcc-4.2 to gcc and then installing:

```
rvm install 1.9.3                       
ERROR: The autodetected CC(/usr/bin/gcc-4.2) is LLVM based, it is not yet fully supported by ruby and gems, please read `rvm requirements`, and set CC=/path/to/gcc .
```

So I could probably just grab gcc elsewhere, but I'm mostly concerned as to why this is happening. Shouldn't installing Xcode be enough?

config.log:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.68.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/Users/jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml-dir=/Users/jamie/.rvm/usr

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Wilson.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 11.2.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 11.2.0: Tue Aug  9 20:54:00 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.24.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 11.2.0: Tue Aug  9 20:54:00 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.24.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
4 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: i486 (Intel 80486)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 8.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 110 tasks, 546 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 1.28, Mach factor: 2.71
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /Users/jamie/.rvm/usr/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/X11/bin
PATH: /Users/jamie/bin
PATH: /Users/jamie/.rvm/bin
PATH: /Users/jamie/.rvm/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2764: checking build system type
configure:2778: result: x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0
configure:2849: checking host system type
configure:2862: result: x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0
configure:2882: checking target system type
configure:2895: result: x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0
configure:3376: checking for C compiler version
configure:3385: gcc-4.2 --version >&5
./configure: line 3387: gcc-4.2: command not found
configure:3396: $? = 127
configure:3385: gcc-4.2 -v >&5
./configure: line 3387: gcc-4.2: command not found
configure:3396: $? = 127
configure:3385: gcc-4.2 -V >&5
./configure: line 3387: gcc-4.2: command not found
configure:3396: $? = 127
configure:3385: gcc-4.2 -qversion >&5
./configure: line 3387: gcc-4.2: command not found
configure:3396: $? = 127
configure:3416: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3438: gcc-4.2    conftest.c  >&5
./configure: line 3440: gcc-4.2: command not found
configure:3442: $? = 127
configure:3480: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3485: error: in `/Users/jamie/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0':
configure:3487: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0
ac_cv_prog_CC=gcc-4.2
ac_cv_target=x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ALLOCA=''
AR=''
ARCHFILE=''
ARCH_FLAG=''
AS=''
ASFLAGS=''
BASERUBY='ruby'
BUILTIN_ENCOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS=''
CAPITARGET=''
CC='gcc-4.2'
CCDLFLAGS=''
CFLAGS=''
CHDIR=''
COMMON_HEADERS=''
COMMON_LIBS=''
COMMON_MACROS=''
COUTFLAG=''
CP=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CPPOUTFILE=''
CXX='g++-4.2'
CXXFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DLDFLAGS=''
DLDLIBS=''
DLEXT2=''
DLEXT=''
DLLWRAP=''
DOT=''
DOXYGEN=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_SHARED=''
EXECUTABLE_EXTS=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPORT_PREFIX=''
EXTOUT=''
EXTSTATIC=''
GCC=''
GNU_LD=''
GREP=''
INSTALLDOC=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDSHARED=''
LDSHAREDXX=''
LIBEXT=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBPATHENV=''
LIBPATHFLAG=''
LIBRUBY=''
LIBRUBYARG=''
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED=''
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC=''
LIBRUBY_A=''
LIBRUBY_ALIASES=''
LIBRUBY_DLDFLAGS=''
LIBRUBY_LDSHARED=''
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE=''
LIBRUBY_SO=''
LIBS=''
LINK_SO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINLIBS=''
MAJOR='1'
MAKEDIRS=''
MAKEFILES=''
MANTYPE=''
MINIOBJS=''
MINIRUBY=''
MINOR='9'
MKDIR_P=''
NM=''
NROFF=''
NULLCMD=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OUTFLAG=''
PACKAGE=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PREP=''
RANLIB=''
RDOCTARGET=''
RI_BASE_NAME=''
RM=''
RMALL=''
RMDIR=''
RMDIRS=''
RPATHFLAG=''
RUBYW_BASE_NAME='rubyw'
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_BASE_NAME='ruby'
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION='1.9.3'
RUBY_RELEASE_DATE='2011-10-30'
RUBY_SO_NAME=''
RUNRUBY=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SOLIBS=''
STATIC=''
STRIP=''
SYMBOL_PREFIX=''
TEENY='1'
TEST_RUNNABLE=''
THREAD_MODEL=''
TRY_LINK=''
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES=''
UNIVERSAL_INTS=''
USE_RUBYGEMS=''
WERRORFLAG=''
WINDRES=''
XCFLAGS=''
XLDFLAGS=''
XRUBY=''
XRUBY_LIBDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYHDRDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYLIBDIR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_OBJCOPY=''
ac_ct_OBJDUMP=''
arch=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='darwin11.2.0'
build_vendor='apple'
cflags=' ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}'
configure_args=''
cppflags=''
cxxflags=' ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
debugflags=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec=''
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='darwin11.2.0'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
optflags=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/Users/jamie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0'
program_transform_name='s&^&&'
psdir='${docdir}'
ridir=''
ruby_pc=''
ruby_version=''
rubyhdrdir=''
rubylibprefix=''
rubyw_install_name=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
setup=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sitearch=''
sitedir=''
sitehdrdir=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_os='darwin11.2.0'
target_vendor='apple'
try_header=''
vendordir=''
vendorhdrdir=''
warnflags=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `CC=/usr/bin/gcc`?

Comment: Anything interesting in the `config.log` file?

Comment: Hmm; I have the same gcc, and it installed fine :( Second thing on SO that has worked fine for me but not for someone else; usually it's the opposite.

Comment: mu: I've added the whole config.log now. Nothing unusual to my eyes. This is the version without a symlink.
Dave: Well, that's computers :-).

Comment: Thanks to help from @mpapis, I've documented [How to Install RVM on Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) with Xcode 4.5 without Installing Command Line Tools](https://gist.github.com/3789921).

Answer (score 553, accepted):

> This answer was edited multiple times and now contains several *alternative* solutions. Try the simple “Edit 3” solution first.

[Ruby 1.9.3-p125 and later have official support for clang](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2012/02/16/ruby-1-9-3-p125-is-released/), so if you are installing such a version you should not need GCC. If you’re installing an older version of Ruby, read on.

To compile Ruby with GCC, you need a non-LLVM version of GCC, which is no longer included with Xcode 4.2. Install it yourself (or downgrade to Xcode 4.1 temporarily), then do `CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3 --enable-shared` (substituting the path to your non-LLVM gcc).

Edit: https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/downloads may help for installing GCC. There is also some info available by running `rvm requirements`.

Edit 2: For an easier solution, you can try adding `--with-gcc=clang` to the arguments to `configure` for Ruby to use clang instead of GCC.

**Edit 3**: `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang` does that for you.

Note: With current versions of Xcode you need to install the command-line tools separately from the Xcode menu -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Components. This is a pre-requisite for doing any compiling with Xcode on the command-line, not just Ruby.

Note 2: If something doesn't work after following the steps, try doing a reboot or re-login to ensure that the environment gets set correctly.

Note 3: Ruby versions prior to 1.9.3-p125 may not always be fully compatible with clang, so test your software thoroughly if using the “edit 3” solution in a production environment.

Comment: The GCC-10.7.pkg didn't do it for me – I think it may only work on 10.7.0 (I'm running 10.7.2), but perhaps the v2 pkg works. Anyway, --with-gcc=clang did it for me! Thanks!

Comment: edit3 didn'work for me (Xcode 4.2.1), but after installing readline `rvm pkg install readline` and passing an extra parameter `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr` it installed successfully.

Comment: Edit3 : doesn't work, Try to install the gcc separately from https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/downloads

Comment: Edit 3, boom! Did 1.9.2 instead of 1.9.3 with no problem

Comment: Thank you so much!, we can finally work on these ruby projects with our lion machines again! You are a life saver!

Comment: Edit 3 Initially didn't work for me, but after restarting my machine it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks edit 3 worked straight away (OS X 10.7.2) for ruby 1.9.3

Comment: For me on OS X 10.7.2 with Xcode 4.2.1 already installed I needed to download/install the GCC as suggested, then reinstall xcode 4.2.1, then new terminal window and finally edit 3 worked.  Thanks.

Comment: just tell configure to search for `correct` gcc - see my answer below

Comment: @stefanB That's basically what the solution in edits 2 & 3 is, except that many users will not have the “correct” (non-LLVM) `gcc` installed and therefore `clang` is the better choice. (See comments above; edit 3 is the simple one-liner that apparently works for most people.)

Comment: The comment by leandro helped me.  It may apply to Lion / XCode 4.2 users if Edit 3 still fails with the messages "checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/someone/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables" in the configure.log

Comment: As noted in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8007305/402618), there is another alternative. `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang` worked for me, but it is not fully supported. You can also use `CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3 --enable-shared`, which seems better supported. I used `osx-gcc-installer` to get 4.2, I believe.

Comment: I had to run rvm cleanup sources then --with-gcc=clang worked

Comment: I'm on Lion with XCode 4.3.1 installed and the latest RVM (1.10.2). The only approach which worked for me was `sudo CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3 --enable-shared`. Edit 3 just didn't work for me.

Comment: @tomtheguvnor Hmm, I just tried this again with the same versions of XCode, RVM, and Lion, and it worked with edit 3. Did you install the command-line tools from XCode 4.3.1 preferences?

Comment: @Arkku No I hadn't installed the command-line tools. I just installed them and retried installing 1.9.3 using `sudo rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang` and it worked! So thanks. Perhaps update edit 3 to hint that you need command-line tools installed?

Comment: And if nothing that was written above works and you already tried "rvm install 1.9.3", try this: "rvm reinstall 1.9.3". It will work!

Comment: Unfortunately, using the clang compiler actually caused a ton of seg faults. I had to use the older GCC compiler via homebrew, and the seg faults went away. Just wanted to add this in case it helps someone in the future.

Comment: @JohnK.Chow Do you mean segfaults when compiling or when running Ruby? I haven't experienced either problem, and I've been running the clang-compiled version ever since before posting this answer.

Comment: @Arkku When running Ruby, specifically when we're running our rspec. I'm running OSX Mountain Lion. Even on our Ubuntu machine (12.04 LTS), it had the exact same seg faults. For our Ubuntu machine, we were running 4.4.1. On our Ubuntu machines, we re-compiled our Ruby with 4.2.3 GCC, and it works like a charm.

Comment: I have discovered a truly marvelous solution to this, which this character-limit is too short to contain. ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/12737471/242933

Comment: Fixed! "With current versions of XCode you need to install the command-line tools separately from the XCode menu -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Components. This is a pre-requisite for doing any compiling with XCode on the command-line, not just Ruby." Just install the command line tools. That's it.

Answer (score 22):

SUMMARY FOR STACK OVERFLOW

I was trying to install SiriProxy on a clean Lion installation on Xcode from App Store

I kept getting errors like :
The provided CC(/usr/bin/gcc) is LLVM based.

```
bash-3.2$ rvm install 1.9.3
ERROR: The provided CC(/usr/bin/gcc) is LLVM based, it is not yet fully supported by ruby and gems, please read `rvm requirements`.
```

After 2 days finally **got it working with these two lines:**

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000145/ruby-rvm-llvm-and-mysql

bash-3.2$ rvm get head
bash-3.2$ CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3 --enable-shared
```

Before that I had tried every stackoverflow article on Ruby and Lion so doing these may have done some setup that helped the above 2 steps work:

Things I tried included:

Running Install Xcode.app (I had downloaded from App Store - running this does futher installation)

Installing

```
https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/downloads may help for installing GCC.
```

Set up CC in

more /Users//.bash_profile

```
bash-3.2$ more /Users/<USERNAME>/.bash_profile 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
export CC=/usr/share/TargetConfigs/bin/gcc
```

First line came from SiriProxy install instruction
https://github.com/plamoni/SiriProxy

2nd line export CC never seemed to work. So dont add.

It had many versions each pointing
I finally used CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3 --enable-shared

Comment: Did you try `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang`?

Comment: CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3 --enable-shared, worked on Snow Leopard with Xcode 4.2, thank you!

Comment: I'd advise against `rvm get head` for other users.  This pulls from the head of the git repo and may not be stable.  `rvm get latest` grabs the latest stable version.  If this doesn't fix this issue for you, the `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang` is worth a shot first since it's less likely to introduce side effects

Answer (score 18):

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

Worked for me. This was on a brand new Lion with Xcode (had no "traditional" GCC).

Answer (score 8):

OK I didn't have to install gcc-4.2 separately, I used the one delivered in Xcode, but I had an issue where the `--with-gcc=clang` wasn't getting passed through. Added the following line to my `.rvmrc`:

```
export rvm_configure_flags="--with-gcc=clang"
```

Worked as required

```
rvm upgrade ruby-1.9.2-p290 ruby-1.9.3-p125
...
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #extracted to /Users/leif/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #configuring
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #compiling 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #installing
....
Successfully migrated ruby-1.9.2-p290 to ruby-1.9.3-p125
Upgrade complete!

bang:$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
```

Note my env is the following

OS

```
Darwin bang.local 11.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.3.0: Thu Jan 12 18:47:41 PST 2012; root:xnu-1699.24.23~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Xcode

```
Xcode 4.2.1 Build 4D502
```

GCC

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)

lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  12 22 Dec 21:30 /usr/bin/gcc -> llvm-gcc-4.2
```

I tried using the answer of passing  `--with-gcc=clang` on the command line to the rvm upgrade command, but it didn't work, it didn't appear to get pass from rvm to configure. Apparently the problem in RVM of arguments not being passed to configure is fixed (in commit `1641ceb0` in 2011), but even after upgrading RVM to latest (via `rvm get latest`) it still didn't get passed. Using the `.rvmrc` file was the only way it would work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Only answering here because I can can't up vote/comment on leandro's comment on the original question.  After spending days trying to get this to work, His solution was the one that *finally* got it working for me:

edit3 didn'work for me (Xcode 4.2.1), but after installing readline

```
 rvm pkg install readline
```

and passing an extra parameter

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

it installed successfully.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to install [Command Line Tools for Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action), it includes GCC, LLMV and other tools that excluded in Xcode 4.2 and higher.

Answer (score 4):

I will suggest [brew](https://brew.sh/) from `rvm requirements` I have installed it while I have already installed latest Xcode Version 4.4 (4F250)

> Homebrew:
>
> If you are using Homebrew, you can install the apple-gcc42 and
> required libraries from homebrew/dupes:
>
> ```
>   brew update
>   brew tap homebrew/dupes
>   brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42
>   rvm pkg install openssl
> ```
>
> This can live side by side with an existing Xcode 4.2+ install or
> Command Line Tools for Xcode.

And you can always do

```
$ brew cleanup [specific-formula or without-formula to clean all]
```

and then if necessary

```
$ brew remove apple-gcc42
```

or any other installed program through brew (see the docs for explanation on those 2 commands), also you can

```
/join #machomebrew
```

on freenode (not #homebrew I think that is real homebrew beer and related)

Answer (score 1):

**Just tell configure to use gcc instead of gcc-4.2** on Lion (Mac OSX 10.7.2)

**Compiling ruby-1.9.3 from source**

You can see in your configure output:

```
configure:3385: gcc-4.2 --version >&5
./configure: line 3387: gcc-4.2: command not found
```

If you search the `config.log` you see:

```
CC='gcc-4.2'
```

I had the same problem, so I run `configure` while selecting `gcc` instead of `gcc-4.2`:

```
> CC=gcc ./configure --prefix=/usr/local 
> make
> make install
> ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
```

(I'm not sure what is the `configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libyaml-dir` in your output I guess you figured that one out?)

Comment: Note that the OP symlinked `gcc` to `gcc-4.2`, which made the command available but revealed the underlying problem that their `gcc` was actually `llvm-gcc` (and no non-LLVM GCC was installed).

Answer (score 1):

Download and use [JewelryBox](http://unfiniti.com/software/mac/jewelrybox) The official RVM GUI for Mac OS. Inside "Add Ruby" select your version of Ruby. Before installing, make sure you select "Use Clang" just as what **Edit 3** of the accepted answer in this thread suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Got same issue, since I am using Xcode 4.3.2 and Lion 10.7.3, and I changed my laptop few days ago and then transfer all contents from the old laptop. Apparently, some of binaries not get transfer over, such as gcc.

ANd then I did following:

1. Remove Xcode 4.3.2 by dragging it to trash
2. Download the gcc install package v2 from https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/downloads
3. Install it
4. Then rvm install 1.9.2 working for me

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure you're on the latest rvm.**  Using rvm 1.10.0 none of the above worked for me.  Furthermore, `rvm get latest` erroneously told me "You already have the latest version!" so I had to `rvm implode` and reinstall rvm (1.15.4), which automatically gave me ruby 1.9.3-p194 with no fuss.

Answer (score 1):

For me, none of the above worked as-is. What finally worked was

```
rvm get head
rm -rf  /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3*
CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3 --enable-shared
```

The special trick was to remove the libsqllite that, according to the build log, was missing the required 64-bit architecture or something.

Answer (score 1):

A more recent simpler solution is to just use [railsinstaller.org](http://railsinstaller.org/). It has osx-gcc packaged within it, so it's as easy as a download and install. After meddling with a new shell recently, i landed up mucking my rails environment. After trying many of the above solutions (which previously worked I might add), I landed up following the below steps to get things working again:

- nuke your local environment, (think rvm implode and uninstall Xcode)
- download the pkg from [railsinstaller.org](http://railsinstaller.org/)
- double click and install

The installer takes some time considering it installs git, rvm , homebrew and a bunch of other goodies.

Answer (score 1):

With brew you can install ruby in a one-liner:

```
brew install ruby193
```

Worked out of the box for me on OS X 10.8.4. (If you want 2.0, just run `brew install ruby` instead)

More generally, `brew search ruby` shows you the different repos available, and if you want to get really specific you can use `brew versions ruby` and checkout a specific version instead.

You might need Xcode and command-line tools, but brew's setup will check all that for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

> rvm install 1.9.3 --force-autoconf