# Error while installing Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.1.3 on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

I've an error when I want to install Ruby 1.9.3 on OS X. I've seen most of the problem come from xCode not being installed. So, I installed it and I still have the problem, so, here it is:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Arnaud:~ Arnaud$ rvm install 1.9.3
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0, this may take a >while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #extracted to /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0 (already extracted)
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Compiling yaml in /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Installing yaml to /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/usr
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #configuring 
ERROR: Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/Arnaud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml-dir=/Users/Arnaud/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/Arnaud/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/configure.log
ERROR: There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

So, I decide to let the 1.8.7 and direct go to Rails and the install seems to go well, but nothing is istall :/

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Arnaud:~ Arnaud$ sudo gem install rails
Password:
Successfully installed rails-3.1.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.1.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.1.3...
MacBook-Pro-de-Arnaud:~ Arnaud$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***


MacBook-Pro-de-Arnaud:~ Arnaud$ rail
-bash: rail: command not found
MacBook-Pro-de-Arnaud:~ Arnaud$ rails
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

Would anyone have a solution ?

Comment: 1) Did you actually read the `configure.log` file as suggested when installing 1.9.3? 2) Try running `gem env` and see what version of ruby & rubygems you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8237833) worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem with Ruby 1.9.3.

After going through the logs and trolling the internet I found that I had to:

1 - install GCC
2 - link to 64 bit libraries
3 - reinstall rails and sqlite3

I've noted what I did [here](http://mrg-techblog.blogspot.com/2011/12/ruby-193-and-rails-313-on-mac-os-x-lion.html) to remember what I did, and hopefully help someone else who is having similar issues.