# RVM ruby installation errors - Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

I have tried to install each of the following three versions of Ruby via RVM, each with their own set of errors. I'm more concerned with getting the last one working so I'll focus on that.

```
rvm install 1.8.7
rvm install 1.9.2
rvm install 1.9.3
```

**rvm install 1.9.3 (bash output)**

```
14:10:41: ~/.rvm/config $ 
rvm install 1.9.3
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/src
ERROR: Error running 'tar mzxf /Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/archives/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz -C  /Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/src ', please read /Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/yaml/extract.log
Configuring yaml in /Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
ERROR: Error running ' ./configure --prefix="/Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/usr"  ', please read /Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
ERROR: Error running 'make ', please read /Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/yaml/make.log
Database file /Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/config/packages does not exist.    
/Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/scripts/functions/build: line 19: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...   
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #extracted to /Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #configuring 
ERROR: Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/configure.log
ERROR: There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
14:20:14: ~/.rvm/config $
```

**configure.log output**

```
14:20:14: ~/.rvm/config $ 
cat ~/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/configure.log 
[2012-01-11 14:20:12]  ./configure --prefix=/Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/rubies/ruby-    1.9.3-p0 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-    dir=/Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/usr 
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libyaml
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin11.2.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

See `config.log' 

for more details
14:27:45: ~/.rvm/config $
```

**make.log output**

```
cat ~/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/yaml/make.log
[2012-01-11 14:20:12] make 
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

**Specs and short summary of steps I have taken**
MacBook Air
13-inch, Mid 2011
Software  Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2 (11C74)

- Installed RVM
- Tried to install ruby via rvm
- Figured there may be an xcode / gcc compiler problem, so installed xcode from app store
- Tried again to install ruby via rvm, failed
- Tried to reinstall xcode incase the installation didn't complete properly
- Exported GCC to path as suggested by someone who experienced a similar problem
- Tried again to install ruby via rvm, failed

If anyone has any suggestions I'd be grateful.

Thanks guys.

**edit: **

**GCC -v**

```
15:15:32: ~ $ 
  gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.1~22/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.1~22/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
15:15:51: ~ $
```

**extract.log output**

```
15:15:25: ~ $ 
  cat ~/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/yaml/extract.log
[2012-01-11 15:14:56] tar mzxf /Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/archives/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz -C /Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/src 
yaml-0.1.4/tests/example-reformatter-alt.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/tests/example-deconstructor.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/tests/test-reader.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/tests/Makefile.am: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/tests/test-version.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/tests/run-dumper.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/tests/run-emitter.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/tests/run-parser.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/tests/run-scanner.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/tests/run-loader.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/tests/Makefile.in: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/tests/example-reformatter.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/tests/example-deconstructor-alt.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/config.h.in: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/aclocal.m4: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/Makefile.am: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/configure: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/yaml-0.1.pc.in: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/LICENSE: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/README: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/include/Makefile.am: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/include/yaml.h: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/include/Makefile.in: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/Makefile.in: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/configure.ac: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/config/ltmain.sh: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/config/config.sub: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/config/missing: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/config/config.guess: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/config/install-sh: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/config/depcomp: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/doxygen.cfg: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x6c.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x74.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/doxygen.css: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x69.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x6f.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/structyaml__event__s.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/files.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/tab_h.png: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x74.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x72.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/group__tokens.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x64.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/group__emitter.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/bc_s.png: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x77.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x6b.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/structyaml__parser__s.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x62.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x76.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x66.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x72.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/index.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x63.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/structyaml__mark__s.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/structyaml__alias__data__s.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/closed.png: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/group__version.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x75.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/annotated.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x64.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/structyaml__document__s.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/modules.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x65.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x6d.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x6d.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/tabs.css: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/globals_enum.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x71.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x63.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/structyaml__tag__directive__s.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/classes.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x77.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x68.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x6b.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x71.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/doxygen.png: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/open.png: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x70.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/yaml_8h.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/structyaml__node__s.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x75.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x68.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/tab_a.png: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x73.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/nav_f.png: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x73.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/tab_s.png: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/globals_eval.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x69.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/structyaml__token__s.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x65.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x62.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/group__nodes.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/structyaml__emitter__s.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/group__export.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x6e.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/group__parser.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/globals_type.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x6f.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x76.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/globals_defs.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/globals.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/structyaml__node__pair__s.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x6e.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/group__events.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x66.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_0x6c.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/globals_func.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/tab_b.png: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/nav_h.png: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/functions_vars_0x70.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/group__basic.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/structyaml__simple__key__s.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/group__styles.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/doc/html/structyaml__version__directive__s.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/src/parser.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/src/reader.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/src/Makefile.am: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/src/emitter.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/src/writer.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/src/api.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/src/dumper.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/src/Makefile.in: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/src/yaml_private.h: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/src/scanner.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/src/loader.c: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/Makefile.am: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2003/example_deconstructor_alt.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2003/run_scanner.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2003/example_reformatter_alt.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2003/test_reader.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2003/example_deconstructor.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2003/run_dumper.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2003/libyaml.sln: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2003/run_parser.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2003/yaml.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2003/test_version.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2003/run_emitter.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2003/example_reformatter.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2003/run_loader.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2003/yamldll.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vc6/run_emitter.dsp: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vc6/run_dumper.dsp: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vc6/example_deconstructor_alt.dsp: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vc6/yaml.dsp: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vc6/run_parser.dsp: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vc6/example_deconstructor.dsp: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vc6/example_reformatter_alt.dsp: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vc6/run_scanner.dsp: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vc6/run_loader.dsp: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vc6/test_reader.dsp: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vc6/libyaml.dsw: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vc6/example_reformatter.dsp: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vc6/yamldll.dsp: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vc6/test_version.dsp: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/Makefile.in: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/example_deconstructor_alt.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/run_scanner.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/example_reformatter_alt.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/test_reader.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/example_deconstructor.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/run_dumper.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/libyaml.sln: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/run_parser.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/yaml.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/test_version.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/run_emitter.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/example_reformatter.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/run_loader.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/vs2008/yamldll.vcproj: Can't unlink already-existing object
yaml-0.1.4/win32/config.h: Can't unlink already-existing object
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

Comment: Can you also post the content of 
    /Users/dionnesaunders/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/yaml/extract.log

Comment: what does `gcc -v` at the commandline show?

Comment: added output of log & gcc -v to the bottom of the question. thanks.

Comment: Similar to question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032824/cant-install-ruby-under-lion-with-rvm-gcc-issues

Comment: yes, and with the same solution. wish I saw this earlier, thanks =)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

Comment: I ran into this same issue while trying to install 1.9.3-p194 and it took me hours to work through it. This answer helped a lot, and so did this link: http://moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/. What finally worked for me was to go through all this BS and then go into the .rvm/archives folder and remove the ruby-1.9.3-p194.tar.bz2 before trying the installation again. I'm definitely checking out rbenv the next time I have to go through something like this.

Comment: i had following issues:clang: error: unsupported option '--with-libyaml'
Ruby 'ruby-1.9.3-p194' was built using clang - but it's not (fully) supported, expect errors.

Comment: I actually haven't encountered any subsequent errors once I had installed it with clang.

Comment: It's buggy for me. I can't even run bundler without running into an error.

Comment: It may be possible that there are differences between our environments. I am still yet to experience anything strange. Out of interest, which OS are you running?

Answer (score 17):

If you have a new install of XCode, you'll need to:

1.) open it

2.) go to: Preferences>Downloads>Command Line Tools

3.) install the Command Line Tools

4.) then run the following in Terminal:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the correct answer for me.  Not sure why installing the command line tools is so contrived!

Comment: Another way to install the xcode command line tools is to use:       xcode-select --install

Answer (score 4):

Did you install libyaml package before installing ruby 1.8.7?

Since rvm is showing a `Error running 'make`, you should also install readline package using

`rvm pkg install readline`

You should install all the necessary rvm packages before installing any version of ruby. If you have installed any version of ruby before installing those packages, you should remove them using

```
rvm remove 1.8.7
rvm remove 1.9.2
rvm remove 1.9.3
```

And then install them again using

```
rvm install 1.8.7
rvm install 1.9.2
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Comment: did you use `rvm pkg install libyaml`

Comment: oh no I didn't. I used brew I think. However, when I try via rvm it errors as well.

Comment: I've just tried installing readline, it was successfully installed but did not solve any ruby installation issues unfortunately. thanks for the tip though

Comment: after installing your packages. Uninstall all of the versions of ruby and then install them again

Comment: there were no versions of Ruby installed to uninstall. This is a fresh machine and installing via RVM was my first attempt.

Comment: `rvm implode` and then reinstalling did it for me, after swapping my hard drive in to a new macbook.  Also I updated xcode dev tools and did `brew install apple-gcc42` beforehand, don't know if they had any effect.

Answer (score 2):

I used homebrew to install GCC-4.2, then symlinked it from /usr/local/bin to /usr/bin. This fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely related to the gcc you are using.  Have you tired to use non llvm gcc compiler?  You will most likely find it under /Xcode4/usr/bin/gcc-4.2

so:

```
$> export CC=/Xcode4/user/bin/gcc-4.2 && rvm install 1.8.7
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah I did try this, I found that it has helped other people (google) sadly it didn't solve my issue. thanks though.

Comment: If you have XCode from AppStore then you need to change the command to 'export CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc && rvm install 1.8.7'

Answer (score 0):

Consider installing [OSX GCC](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/downloads), it will solve many of the problems occurred from Xcode installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually download the file `yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz` and place it in the proper directory for rvm.

The failure for me was curl could not get the file and the error had to do with a failed certificate check. I have `GCC-10.7-v2.pkg` installed so the C compiler can do its work because my newer version of Xcode did not have `GCC` included.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by installing https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop
Every time I try running ruby on rails, I get stuck and then give up. This time I made it