# Install any version of ruby with RVM on mavericks

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mavericks

I've just upgraded to osx mavericks, and I want to install ruby 2.0, but I'm getting `configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.` errors.

I update rvm with `rvm get stable` and then type `rvm install 2.0.0` and get an error directing me to a log file. The log file contains:

```
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/Users/mattroberts/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p247':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

So, I tried listing the versions I do have. It tells me i have `1.9.3-p392` so I uninstall that one and re-install to see if that works - same error.

Do I need to re-install / update xcode, or is there another solution?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813889/rvm-ruby-installation-errors-mac/10593275#10593275

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you haven't upgraded Xcode after upgrading to Mavericks you should do so
After that, open a command prompt and type:
`xcode-select --install`

This will install xcode command tools that have been deleted by OSX update.
After that it should work okay.

Comment: Yay, updating xcode did the trick for me - I didn't need to `xcode-select --install` though

Comment: Oddly enough, I was on XCode 5 and I still needed to upgrade to 5.0.2 and still had to run the above command.

Comment: This was failing with a "not available" error for me. In case that happens to anyone else: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110463/xcode-select-install-not-available-on-update-server

Comment: Is this only vlid for Mavericks? (10.8 says "xcode-select: Error: unknown command option '--install'.)

Comment: In addition to installing the command line tools with the above command I had to open Xcode. I guess this is required if Xcode has been installed but never run, which was the case for me.

Comment: all `xcode-select --install` does for me is `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`. I had to

Answer (score 29):

The suggested solutions did not solve my issue (XCode at newest version, command line tools installed). I used `rvm install ruby-1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang` and that worked.

I thought rvm used to use clang for OSX by default. Not sure if I remember that wrong or something changed / this is no longer the best thing to do. Nevertheless it made the install work for me.

After Edu's comment, the [github rvm issues page](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2133) he referenced warns:

> @marksands please be sure you know what you are duing, ruby 1.9.3
>   compiled with clang is not "safe", it can segfault, thread related
>   issues to be expected, consider reinstalling ruby --with-gcc=gcc42 or
>   just let rvm install gcc 4.6, only ruby 2.0.0 is fully compatible with
>   clang

[This issue](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2239) points out issue with gcc46 on Mavericks:

> The gem in question uses different language - not C/C++, it uses
>   Objective-C - so it's not the compiler fault, you can build gcc-4.6
>   with support for Objective-C - it's just not done by default.
>
> You have two options now, both start with uninstallig gcc-4.6 and
>   then:
>
> • Install apple-gcc42
>
> • Install gcc-4.6 with --enable-objc

Comment: also worked on Mavericks: rvm install ruby-1.8.7-p302 --with-gcc=clang

Comment: Installing with clang it's not safe. https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2133

Comment: brew install gcc46 --enable-objc is what worked for me.

Comment: Note that in case of a failed installation, you'll already have brew's `gcc` installed (currently `gcc48`) and you'll need to first uninstall it before re-installing with `--enable-objc` or `--enable-all-languages`.

Answer (score 8):

this is supposed to be fixed, run:

```
rvm get head
rvm remove 1.9.3
rvm install 1.9.3
```

do not use extra flags

Comment: I'm getting the following message in my configure.log:

[2013-10-31 11:59:14] ./configure
...
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/Ann/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p448':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

Comment: what is in `/Users/Ann/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p448/config.log`

Comment: I get the exact same error. Here is the config.log: https://gist.github.com/jaimeohm/7377415

Comment: run `sudo port uninstall apple-gcc42` and then again the commands from answer

Answer (score 3):

What ended up working for me was installing XCode **then RUNNING Xcode** then trying to reinstall.

Comment: +1 So crazy that it may just work... and it did! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: When you update Xcode, it wants you to accept license terms, and from the prefs menu you must install the dev tools, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
rvm_configure_env=('LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib' 'CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include' 'CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include')
```

Corrected my compiler issue in Mavericks

Answer (score 1):

## Solution:

`unset SDKROOT`

This worked for me. I hope it would for you too.

I tried to reinstall xcode along with xcode developer tools. Didn’t work. The same error.

Try to run with `env -i bash —noprofile —norc` to see whether your env vars are causing the issue to further investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the very same issue (on 10.8.5, all up to date). Ruby 2.0.0 installed fine, but not 1.9.3. This solution worked for me.

cd into the ruby path (found in config.log), then
issue `.configure` (with all options, as found in config.log)

```
make
make install
```

Then:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --create
```