# yosemite gem install fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, gcc, rubygems

I am unable to run my bundle install after I upgraded to yosemite, the contents of mkmf.log are as follows

> `/usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6 -o conftest
>   -I/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.4.0
>   -I/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward
>   -I/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include  -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fno-common -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib      -lruby.1.9.1  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc`

and it seems like it is trying to use gcc-4.6 but when I do gcc -v it gives me this

> `Configured with:
>   --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn) Target:
>   x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0 Thread model: posix`

I also tried doing a ln -s to link `/usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6` but it was no help, I keep getting

> `/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby extconf.rb  checking
>   if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not
>   create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
>   libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details. 
>   You may need configuration options.`.

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: What gem you try to install?
Did you install ruby before update to yosemite?

Comment: the bundle fails while installing nokogiri, yes I was working with ruby on rails on mountain lion before and then I upgraded to yosemite

Answer (score 0):

try reinstall ruby with:

```
rvm get stable
rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p547
```

then `bundle install`

Comment: got this while doing that

`checking whether the C compiler works... no`
`configure: error: in `/Users/mac/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p547':`
`configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables`

Comment: I guess I'm using both because I have installed xcode and I also downloaded and installed command line tools from apple

Comment: May be any of this will help http://superuser.com/questions/759363/upgraded-to-mavericks-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594719/install-any-version-of-ruby-with-rvm-on-mavericks

Comment: Did you try `xcode-select --install` ? If it doesn't help then I don't know how to fix it

Comment: yes I did and it did not help after installing, thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - turns out, I had to reinstall ruby in the newest version and build all gems pristine.

http://danielpuglisi.com/articles/2014/10/reinstall-ruby-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite

This solution worked perfectly, I removed all old versions that were listed in rbenv, then installed ruby 2.1.3 as described in the link, then used gem pristine --all, and I was good to go, no more annoying error messages.

The steps really depends on which one you are using, rbenv or rmv.