# Having problems installing ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, rvm

I installed ruby 1.9.3 by the command `rvm install 1.9.3` on mac's terminal. I got these errors (see below) after I installation. Does anybody have any ideas to solve this?

> Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/Keta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl
>   --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
>       showing last 15 lines of /Users/Keta/.rvm/log/1421301212_ruby-1.9.3-p551/configure.log
>       GEM_HOME=/Users/Keta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0
>       PATH=/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/Keta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin:/Users/Keta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/bin:/Users/Keta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/Keta/.rvm/bin
>       GEM_PATH=/Users/Keta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0:/Users/Keta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global
>       command(7): ./configure --prefix=/Users/Keta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl
>   --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared
>       configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
>       checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
>       checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
>       checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
>       checking whether the C compiler works... yes
>       checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
>       checking for suffix of executables... 
>       checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/Users/Keta/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p551':
>       configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
>       If you meant to cross compile, use`--host'.
>       See `config.log' for more details
>       There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.

Comment: Looks like it's trying to cross-compile, what's the content of /Users/Keta/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p551 ?

Comment: @philant there are a lot of files and they are various type of files.

Comment: Did give a look to config.log ?

Comment: Do you know what XCode is?  You can try some of the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594719/install-any-version-of-ruby-with-rvm-on-mavericks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This cleared for me after I ran `xcode-select --install`.  Prior to that I also ran `rvm get head` which may have contributed (but didn't fix the problem by itself.)

Comment: I just tried `xcode-select --install` after `rvm get stable` and works fine here