# Installing texi2html error: Can't unlink already-existing object

Tags: macos, homebrew, macos-mojave

I've been searching quite a while now but couldn't find anything that helped me. I've tried everything stated in these answers:
[RVM ruby installation errors - Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813889/rvm-ruby-installation-errors-mac) ,
[Github- Ruby Installer Issues"](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/issues/20) But nothing helped.

So when I try to install texi2html via home-brew I get this output:

```
==> Verifying texi2html-5.0.tar.gz checksum
tar xf /Users/ar2/Library/Caches/Homebrew/texi2html-5.0.tar.gz -C /private/tmp/texi2html-20180718-71233-q5fub1
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/o.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/L.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/a.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/U.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/E.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/Y.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/aa.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/I.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/c.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/AE.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/oe.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/o.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/L.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/a.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/U.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/E.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/Y.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/aa.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/I.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/c.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/AE.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/oe.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/o.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/L.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/a.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/U.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/E.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/Y.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/aa.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/I.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/c.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/AE.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/oe.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/o.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/L.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/a.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/U.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/E.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/Y.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/aa.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/I.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/c.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/AE.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/oe.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes/o.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes/L.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes/a.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes/U.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes/E.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes/Y.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes/aa.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes/I.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes/c.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes/AE.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes/oe.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/o.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/L.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/a.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/U.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/E.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/Y.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/aa.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/I.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/c.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/AE.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/oe.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/o.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/L.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/a.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/U.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/E.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/Y.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/aa.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/I.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/c.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/AE.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/oe.txt: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/OE.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/C.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/A.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/o.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/ae.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/Y.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/e.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/AA.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/I.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/U.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes/L.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/OE.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/C.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/A.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/o.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/ae.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/Y.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/e.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/AA.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/I.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/U.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes/L.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/OE.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/C.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/A.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/o.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/ae.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/Y.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/e.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/AA.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/I.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/U.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/L.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/OE.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/C.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/A.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/o.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/ae.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/Y.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/e.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/AA.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/I.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/U.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unicode/L.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes/OE.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes/C.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes/A.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes/o.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes/ae.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes/Y.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes/e.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes/AA.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes/I.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes/U.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes/L.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/OE.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/C.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/A.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/o.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/ae.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/Y.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/e.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/AA.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/I.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/U.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_use_nodes_no_unidecode/L.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/OE.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/C.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/A.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/o.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/ae.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/Y.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/e.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/AA.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/I.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/U.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res/nodetest_utf8_use_nodes_no_unidecode/L.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
texi2html-5.0/test/manuals/res/info-stnd/Index.html: Can't unlink already-existing object
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
Error: Failure while executing: tar xf /Users/ar2/Library/Caches/Homebrew/texi2html-5.0.tar.gz -C /private/tmp/texi2html-20180718-71233-q5fub1
```

I already tried deleting the cache-file, reinstalling Ruby and using different versions of Ruby via rvm.
It does not make a difference whether I directly type `brew install texi2html` or something that has texi2html as a requirement (such as `brew install opencv`).
I do not even know whether the problem is caused by Ruby or tar or texi2html itself.

I hope you can help me. Kindest regards, Aaroknight

Comment: The tar archive contains files whose names only differ in case. For example, it contains both `texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/C.txt` and `texi2html-5.0/test/encodings/res_all/nodetest_latin1_use_nodes_no_unicode/c.txt`. You can only extract this on a case-sensitive file system. If your file system is case-insensitive, extracting `c.txt` will overwrite `C.txt`, which is what tar is complaining about in your error message. This problem has nothing to do with Homebrew, Ruby, RVM, tar, or texi2html, but with your system setup.

Comment: I am using macOS 10.14, do you know a possible solution for this problem? If not, thanks anyway. This could help me at least a bit.

Comment: FYI HFS is case-insensitive by default, and I assume the same is true for APFS. Apps by big software vendors (Adobe, Blizard) has had past issues with case-sensitive file systems. I've never seen this problem before, but am running into it attempting to update ffmpeg after installing the latest 10.14 beta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this is a known [issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/29340) with the latest 10.14 beta.

Someone on the 10.14 tracking [issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/28817) recommended using the force-bottle option when installing.

`brew install texi2html --force-bottle`

Comment: Solved my problem on Mojave Beta

Comment: Solved it! Thank you very much!