# Ruby fails on OSX Lion with rbenv

Tags: ruby, osx-lion

I've been trying to install Ruby on my Lion machine (OSX 10.7.3).

I installed rbenv and ruby-build and am trying to get 1.9.2-p290 on my machine. Here is the output of the install failing:

```
$ rbenv install 1.9.2-p290
Downloading http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz...
Installing yaml-0.1.4...
Installed yaml-0.1.4 to /Users/CSC/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290
Downloading http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-p290.tar.gz...
Installing ruby-1.9.2-p290...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/vm/gcqcld015jx025m7qgtxvw0m0000gn/T/ruby-build.20120301140751.6239
Results logged to /var/folders/vm/gcqcld015jx025m7qgtxvw0m0000gn/T/ruby-build.20120301140751.6239.log

Last 10 log lines:
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -I. -I../../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin11.3.0 -I../../.././include -I../../.././ext/racc/cparse -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\" -I'/Users/SamCouch/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/include'  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -pipe  -o cparse.o -c cparse.c
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -dynamic -bundle -o ../../../.ext/x86_64-darwin11.3.0/racc/cparse.bundle cparse.o -L. -L../../.. -L. -L'/Users/SamCouch/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib'  -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc 
compiling readline
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -I. -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin11.3.0 -I../.././include -I../.././ext/readline -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\" -I'/Users/SamCouch/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/include'  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -pipe  -o readline.o -c readline.c
readline.c: In function ‘username_completion_proc_call’:
readline.c:1386: error: ‘username_completion_function’ undeclared (first use in this function)
readline.c:1386: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
readline.c:1386: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[1]: *** [readline.o] Error 1
make: *** [mkmain.sh] Error 1
```

I attempted to troubleshoot the issue, but so far I haven't come up with any solution:

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
$ gcc
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files
$ ruby-build
ruby-build 20120216
usage: ruby-build [-v|--verbose] definition prefix
       ruby-build --definitions
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

As a side note, I've tried other similar suggestions posted here, and none have worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

Per ruby-build [issue #130](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/130) the current workaround is:

`env CC=/usr/bin/gcc rbenv install 1.9.3-p125`

I've just tested this successfully on a system with:

- OS X 10.7.3
- Xcode 4.3.1
- Command Line Tools for Xcode installed (via Xcode > Preferences > Downloads)
- ruby-build @ fbfa944
- rbenv @ 975b45d

Also, pending pull request [#137](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/pull/137) aims to fix this upstream once and for all.

FWIW, lots of folks are shaking out build chain issues with Xcode 4.3.x since it came out.  Expect some instability in any system if you've upgraded to the new toolchain until the collective dust settles.

Comment: For older versions of ruby follow the instructions on the [ruby-build wiki](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/wiki)

Answer (score 5):

There seem to be two or three stack overflow questions related to bugs with using `rbenv` to install ruby `1.9.x` on Mac OS X via `homebrew` / `rbenv` and I have tried the solutions for many of them without luck. Setting the compiler and installing the apple gcc42 compiler via homebrew didn't help ( `brew install apple-gcc42` and `CC=/usr/bin/gcc` - no luck ) so I'm not sure if they are necessary. I'm using the `rbenv` manager and so this is what worked for me when trying to install `1.9.3-p385`

The problem is with the readline as the log shows:

```
readline.c: In function ‘username_completion_proc_call’:
readline.c:1499: error: ‘username_completion_function’ undeclared (first use in this function)
readline.c:1499: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
readline.c:1499: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

So after looking specifically for that error I found the solution:

#### Solution:

```
brew install readline
CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-readline-dir=$(brew --prefix readline)" rbenv install 1.9.3-p385
```

You can chance the `rbenv install 1.9.3-p385` part of the command to match whatever version is latest or that you are trying to install. Found the note on [this blog](http://rors.org/2011/10/25/compiling-ruby-on-a-fresh-lion-install).

Comment: My error wasn't exactly the same "Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/..." but this worked for me.  I'm on Mavericks.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may be answering on the level of what you need rather than on the level of what you're directly asking, but: have you considered simply using macports (see macports.org) or brew as a way of installing ruby 1.9? It works very well and with much less effort.

Comment: Neither Homebrew nor Macports provide a mechanism to select from multiple rubies. RVM and rbenv do, but both currently require a workarounds to build various rubies under the Xcode 4.3 toolchain.  From the rbenv homepage on GitHub, you'll note that it specifically tries to avoid certain problematic approaches embraced by RVM.

Comment: I just checked, and RVM seems to build 1.9.3 using Xcode 4.3 with no trouble at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you were asking for but "[Can't install Ruby under Lion with RVM – GCC issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032824/cant-install-ruby-under-lion-with-rvm-gcc-issues)" answers how to get Ruby working on Lion with RVM.  The errors are pretty similar so you could either:

Use them for some guidance for rbenv troubleshooting, or simply use RVM as described in the top answer to install Ruby that way. It seems like the easier method to me.