# Having difficulty installing rvm 1.9.3 with xcode 4.3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, rvm, xcodebuild

If I type **xcodebuild -version** it recognises that I have xcode installed:

```
Xcode 4.3.2
Build version 4E2002
```

But then when I try to check **rvm requirements** I get the following:

```
Notes for Mac OS X 10.7.3, No Xcode.
For JRuby:  Install the JDK. See http://developer.apple.com/java/download/  # Current Java           version "1.6.0_26"
For IronRuby: Install Mono >= 2.6
For Ruby 1.9.3: Install libksba # If using Homebrew, 'brew install libksba'

You can use & download osx-gcc-installer: https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-   installer
** NOTE: Currently, Node.js is having issues building with osx-gcc-installer. The only fix     is to install Xcode over osx-gcc-installer.

We had reports of http://hpc.sourceforge.net/ making things work, but it looks like not easiest/safest to setup.

To use an RVM installed Ruby as default, instead of the system ruby:

rvm install 1.8.7 # installs patch 357: closest supported version
rvm system ; rvm gemset export system.gems ; rvm 1.8.7 ; rvm gemset import system.gems # migrate your gems
rvm alias create default 1.8.7

And reopen your terminal windows.

Xcode 4.2:
* is only supported by ruby 1.9.3+ using command line flag: --with-gcc=clang
* it breaks gems with native extensions, especially DB drivers.
```

It seems that it is not recognising my xcode and when I try to **install rvm 1.9.3** I get:

```
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running ' ./configure --prefix="/Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/usr"  ', please read             /Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-    p125/yaml/make.log


Database file /Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/config/packages does not exist.

/Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/scripts/functions/build: line 28: --version: command not found
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125, this     may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #extracted to /Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #configuring 
Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125 --    enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-   dir=/Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-    p125/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Now if i read the log, the output of **cat /Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/configure.log** is the following:

```
./configure --prefix=/Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125 --enable-shared --        disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/usr 
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libyaml
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

and the output of **cat /Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/yaml/configure.log** is the following:

```
./configure --prefix="/Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/usr"  
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... config/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/Users/sikandarshukla/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

Any ideas what to do, Thanks for your help

Comment: OK, so I followed some of the tips on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032824/cant-install-ruby-under-lion-with-rvm-gcc-issues#_=_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in recognizing Xcode version, I have created a ticket and it should be solved shortly -> https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/846

All Xcode 4.2+ have the same issue:

> 4.2:
>
> - is only supported by ruby 1.9.3+ using command line flag: --with-gcc=clang
> - it breaks gems with native extensions, especially DB drivers.

To solve use osx-gcc-installer:

> You can use & download osx-gcc-installer: https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

Comment: looks like you fixed this the next day.  Thanks!