# Error: Rack app won't run -- bundler/setup

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-lion, rack-pow

I'm completely new to Ruby (and RoR) and I'm trying to set up a local environment to help work on a site. Ideally, I would work on it locally, and then commit the changes to github and push it further down the pipeline from there.

I'm on a brand new Macbook Pro running OSX Lion.

I have had much trouble trying to get it work:

- Installed Xcode Command Line Tools and RVM couldn't install latest version of ruby because it failed to compile with LLVM (Lion default compiler)
- compiled ruby using a special flag it asked me to use (forgot what it was), but then was having trouble with Postgres and Pow
- Tried installing a standalone GCC to compile ruby correctly thinking it may solve the problem. Pow still gave me errors.

I have tried removing and installing everything I could think of, and still nothing. I stress: I'm a noob.

I finally found a script called *railsready* that sets up ruby and RoR for you (https://github.com/joshfng/railsready) which failed to recognize Xcode since Lion installs it into Applications (the script checked for it by looking for an Xcode .plist file in Library/Developer). The author helped be out by updating the code to look for gcc instead and it tried installing but failed because it couldn't write to my `.bash_profile`. I removed it and tried it again, and it worked.

I installed Pow so I can have it run on a custom domain (website.dev) and have multiple apps under different domains. Now it's giving me this error and I have no idea what it means or how to go about it.

**I would really appreciate any help**. Most ruby guys I talk to have no idea what this is about, and why Lion is so much trouble to set up on. They are on older (Snow Leopard) machines.

### The Error

```
Your Rack app raised an exception when Pow tried to run it.
LoadError: no such file to load -- bundler/setup
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
~/Github/letsordernow/config/boot.rb:6
~/Github/letsordernow/config/application.rb:1:in `require'
~/Github/letsordernow/config/application.rb:1
~/Github/letsordernow/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
~/Github/letsordernow/config/environment.rb:2
~/Github/letsordernow/config.ru:3:in `require'
~/Github/letsordernow/config.ru:3
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.3.2/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in `instance_eval'
~/Library/Application    Support/Pow/Versions/0.3.2/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in `initialize'
~/Github/letsordernow/config.ru:1:in `new'
~/Github/letsordernow/config.ru:1
```

Comment: Did you execute the app with `bundle exec`?

Comment: No, but when I did just now, it returned `bundler: exec needs a command to run`.

Comment: I mean like: `bundle exec start_your_app_command` (whatever that command is).

Comment: See: http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-exec.1.html

Comment: I've read over the page you linked to, and I have no idea what command to use.

I've just tried staring rails server via `bundle exec rails s` and it gave me http://pastie.org/private/vhq8gfxocaut6fctq8ovq

This is not a good start to my relationship with Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Ruby On Rails.  :)

You're going to love the new Rails.app Kickstarter project by Yehuda Katz:

http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1397300529/railsapp

My advice for now:

- Standalone GCC is good. You're doing this right.
- To use RVM with Lion and non-LLVM, read about compiling Ruby with clang:  [Can't install Ruby under Lion with RVM – GCC issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032824/cant-install-ruby-under-lion-with-rvm-gcc-issues)
- In each of your Rails projects, run this which may clean up your Pow issues:

  ```
  bundle install
  ```
- Make sure each of your projects has a .rvmrc file pointing to the correct ruby version and gemset.
- My two cents is to try to get up and running without RVM and Pow to start. These aren't needed and they have quirks with paths and glitches (IMHO). I personally prefer to use bundler to manage gemsets, and the rbenv tool and ruby-build tool for managing Ruby versions. See https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv
- Pow is nifty but tricky. It has a history of quirky setup (IMHO). My two cents is to get up and running with webrick first (i.e. make sure you can do "rails s" to start a local server) and then I personally like Apache and Passenger (or Thin). For Pow help on quirky setup see https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/119

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks for the amazing input! Will definitely back the Rails.app project. I will try to go through all the info you linked me to, and see how far I can get. This is my third day of trying to get this to work and I'm almost ready to give up. If I have no luck, would you be available to do some consulting/installation work via screenshare? I really do appreciate the help, but I'm afraid I will need an experts hand in setting this up soon enough.

Comment: Sure Michal, I can give it a try. My contact info is my username at Google Talk, Skype, etc.