# How to use RVM to install Ruby 1.9.3 when Xcode 4.3.2 is installed and gcc is missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, macos, rvm

I got a new iMac with Lion and installed Xcode 4.3.2.  After running

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

I opened up a new `bash`, and used

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
```

to install Ruby 1.9.3, but there were errors and the log said that the C compiler is not there.  And `rvm requirements` says:

```
$ rvm requirements
  [...]
Xcode 4.3+ users
- please be warned
- only ruby-1.9.3-p125+ is partially supported
- in case of any compilation issues:
 * downgrade to Xcode 4.1
 * uninstall Xcode and install osx-gcc-installer
and reinstall your rubies.
```

So does that mean I might need to downgrade to Xcode 4.1?  What if I want to keep Xcode 4.3.2?  Then will 1.9.3-p125+ be able to work, but only partially?

Update: or how about installing Ruby 1.9.2 -- will it work with the latest Rails 3.2.3?  If so, how to add gcc?  (using Xcode's gcc?)

Comment: What is the output of `cd /tmp ; echo "int main(int argc, char *argv) { return 0; }" > foo.c ; gcc -o foo foo.c ; ./foo && echo success || echo failure` ?

Comment: when I type `gcc` all by itself, it says `-bash: gcc: command not found`

Comment: Try the last piece of advice [on this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8032980/377270): `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang`

Comment: if I use that line, it will say `You requested building with 'clang' but it is not in your path.`

Comment: Go to Xcode, Preferences, Downloads, and install the command line tools. That should help, I hope. I'm using Xcode 4.2, I did install gcc separately. But I read elsewhere that in 4.3, when you install the command line tools, you get gcc (or a gcc wrapper for the clang compiler at least).

Comment: After doing so, it actually does install Ruby 1.9.3... although I haven't used it extensively to see that it is all OK...  Do you know what it means by "partially supported" in the `rvm requirements`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install 1.9.2 or lower you need to follow the instructions in this blog post. It outlines how it get a copy of GCC which does not conflict with Xcode but can be used to build Ruby.

[Xcode 4.3, Homebrew and Ruby](http://jfire.io/blog/2012/03/02/xcode-4-dot-3-homebrew-and-ruby/).

You cannot install the osx-gcc-installer as it will conflict with Xcode 4.3.2, overwriting the working versions of llvm-gcc and clang.

Answer (score -2):

install [osx-gcc-installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/downloads)

use latest ruby:

```
rvm install ruby
```

it will be `1.9.3-p125` as it's latest ruby

Comment: ok that's annoying, that's the fix listed as part of the output of RVM in the the question, it does fix the problem, and you still can use both osx-gcc-installer and Xcode.