# Trouble installing ruby with RVM. Database file does not exist?

Tags: ruby, configuration, rvm

Running into big problems at step one. I got RVM installed, then typed "rvm install 1.9.3" and here's the output:

```
David-Coles-MacBook-Air:~ DavesPiece$ rvm install 1.9.3
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/DavesPiece/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/DavesPiece/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /Users/DavesPiece/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running ' ./configure --prefix="/Users/DavesPiece/.rvm/usr"  ', please read /Users/DavesPiece/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /Users/DavesPiece/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/DavesPiece/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/make.log


Database file /Users/DavesPiece/.rvm/config/packages does not exist.

Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/DavesPiece/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracted to /Users/DavesPiece/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #configuring 
Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/DavesPiece/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/DavesPiece/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/DavesPiece/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
ls: /Users/DavesPiece/.rvm/rubies/*/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
David-Coles-MacBook-Air:~ DavesPiece$
```

I went and read the log files it mentioned but that lead nowhere. Any idea what I should do? I've practically Googled my face off and can't find a solution.

Comment: We have the similar problem on ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

this looks suspicious, how did you installed RVM ?

the simplest solution is to:

```
touch /Users/DavesPiece/.rvm/config/packages
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Xcode, you'll need to install it. If you have Lion 10.7.3 or above you can find it in the App Store. Otherwise, you will need to go to the Apple Developer site (requires account) to find instructions for downloading and installing it.

Also, if you're on Lion, you may need to download and install GCC-10.7-v2.pkg. If you see a message about your compiler being LLVM based, you may need to use this command instead:
CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.2-p290 --enable-shared

Without having seen your configure.log this is just a best guess.

Answer (score 0):

[Can't install Ruby under Lion with RVM – GCC issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032824/cant-install-ruby-under-lion-with-rvm-gcc-issues)