# Install Ruby with Mountain Lion, Xcode 4.5, and RVM?

Tags: ruby, rvm, llvm

`rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang` (as suggested by [Can't install Ruby under Lion with RVM – GCC issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032824/cant-install-ruby-under-lion-with-rvm-gcc-issues)) doesn't work because neither Mac OS X 10.8.2 (Mountain Lion) nor Xcode 4.5 comes with `clang`.

Is it possible to compile Ruby with `llvm`?

According to [Matthias Schmidt's "How to install Ruby 1.9.3 on Mac OS X with LLVM and rbenv"](http://m-schmidt.eu/2012/02/25/how-to-install-ruby-on-mac-os-x-with-llvm-and-rbenv/), Ruby is now fully compatible with LLVM.

But, I still get: `error: C compiler cannot create executables`

#### UPDATE:

Actually, I found `clang` here `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang` (thanks to the [Node.js Installation Wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation)). I just didn't have `clang` in my path.

So, if I add `clang` to my path, is `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang` sufficient?

Comment: this error does not need to be result of compiler itself, sometimes conflicting compilation/environment flags or libraries can cause it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, ruby is not fully compatible with llvm, there is at least one issue with Fibers and other issues might occur if version of llvm changes.

Ruby works best with gcc-4.2, rvm provides information how to get it (+other important stuff):

```
rvm requirements
```

Comment: I found `clang`. So, is `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang` OK?

Comment: clang is not ok, it uses llvm ... unless you have clang version from GNU not llvm.

Comment: Thanks to your help, I've documented a temporary workaround for this issue until it's addressed (in RVM 1.17). [How to Install RVM without Xcode Command Line Tools](https://gist.github.com/3789921)

Answer (score 12):

From RVM notes:

**Homebrew**:

If you are using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), you can install the apple-gcc42 and required libraries from homebrew/dupes:

```
  brew update
  brew tap homebrew/dupes
  brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42
  rvm pkg install openssl
```

This can live side by side with an existing Xcode 4.2+ install or Command Line Tools for Xcode.

**osx-gcc-installer**:

If you don't use Homebrew, you can download and install osx-gcc-installer:
https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I used this: http://railsinstaller.org/mac - and it was a BREEZE.  Also I like the sublime text editor, found that through this resource... Maybe I'll say goodbye to macvim!  Imagine that.