# Installing Ruby - RVM - Mac OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

So I'm trying to install Ruby 1.9.3 on my Mac running Mountain Lion. I have xCode installed and up to date. I've installed RVM and now am trying to install Ruby using `rvm install 1.9.3` When I run this it looks like it's going to install but gives me an error please see below:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p392.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Already up-to-date.
Certificates in '/Users/Colin/.rvm/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/Colin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p392, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #extracted to /Users/Colin/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p392 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #configuring........
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/Colin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392 --with-opt-dir=/Users/Colin/.rvm/opt/libyaml:/Users/Colin/.rvm/opt/readline:/Users/Colin/.rvm/opt/libxml2:/Users/Colin/.rvm/opt/libxslt:/Users/Colin/.rvm/opt/libksba:/Users/Colin/.rvm/opt/openssl:/Users/Colin/.rvm/opt/sqlite --disable-install-doc --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared',
please read /Users/Colin/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p392/1366429269_configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

When I go to the /1366429269_configure.log file it says this:

```
[2013-04-19 20:41:09] ./configure
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/Colin/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p392':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

If anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

I tried the solution here [Can't install Ruby under Lion with RVM – GCC issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032824/cant-install-ruby-under-lion-with-rvm-gcc-issues) `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang` and it changed a bit, here is the new output:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Already up-to-date.
Certificates in '/Users/Colin/.rvm/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Warning: found user selected compiler 'clang', this will suppress RVM auto detection mechanisms.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/Colin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p392, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #extracted to /Users/Colin/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p392 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #configuring.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #compiling..................................................................
Error running 'make -j8',
please read /Users/Colin/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p392/1366431470_make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

And heres the log from that: http://pastebin.com/P6nTZRQY

**EDIT**

Not sure what happened but I just tried the same thing and now it's working perfect. Thank you everyone who left a helpful comment, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try first doing: `rvm get head` then try installing again.

Comment: BTW the title is wrong, you're trying to install `Ruby 1.9.3`, not `Rails`

Comment: Also check out some of the solutions here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032824/cant-install-ruby-under-lion-with-rvm-gcc-issues

Comment: Did you install the Xcode command line tools? It's in the Xcode preferences under "downloads".

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! I believe I have the newest version of RVM. I just installed the Xcode Command tools and tried it again but unfortunately no luck. I have tried doing "rvm get head" as well, same thing. I believe it maybe something to do with the compiler, I'm not sure if I have this installed / how to install it, if someone could please let me know I can do that and give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: In case this comes up in a search, I always recommend this [blogpost](http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/) for getting your dependencies in order before installing Rails.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update Command Line Tools to latest version, also for ruby 1.9.3 it is still preferred to use `gcc-4.2` for compilation.

Also make sure you update RVM before trying again:

```
rvm get head
rvm install 1.9.2
```

Finally, Ruby `2.0.0` should be compatible with `1.9.3` and you should update.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issues trying to install Ruby on Rails on Lion a month ago.  In the end, I used an installer.  If using an installer is a viable option for you, check out the [Rails Installer](http://railsinstaller.org/).

Comment: I gave this a try as well, but kept receiving this error right before installation: http://gyazo.com/fd8ebfa6cd6c4c8f9333dd276efbf03d

Answer (score 1):

try to use this it will install all

```
   wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/joshfng/railsready/master/railsready.sh && bash railsready.sh
```