# rbenv install is failing (telling me to install GCC, but it's already installed)

Tags: gcc, ruby-on-rails-2, rbenv, ruby-1.8.7

So, my client has me working on a legacy app which is running Rails 2.3.8 and Ruby 1.8.7, so I'm attempting to install the proper version of ruby using rbenv but it keeps giving me this error:

```
→ rbenv install 1.8.7-p249

ERROR: This package must be compiled with GCC, but ruby-build couldn't
find a suitable `gcc` executable on your system. Please install GCC
and try again.

DETAILS: Apple no longer includes the official GCC compiler with Xcode
as of version 4.2. Instead, the `gcc` executable is a symlink to
`llvm-gcc`, a modified version of GCC which outputs LLVM bytecode.

For most programs the `llvm-gcc` compiler works fine. However,
versions of Ruby older than 1.9.3-p125 are incompatible with
`llvm-gcc`. To build older versions of Ruby you must have the official
GCC compiler installed on your system.


TO FIX THE PROBLEM: Install the official GCC compiler using these
packages: https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/downloads

You will need to install the official GCC compiler to build older
versions of Ruby even if you have installed Apple's Command Line Tools
for Xcode package. The Command Line Tools for Xcode package only
includes `llvm-gcc`.

BUILD FAILED
```

When I checked to see if I had GCC, it showed that I do:

```
→ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

and

```
→ gcc -v

Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~148/src/configure --disable-   checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~148/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

I've updated rbenv. Not really sure what else to do.

Comment: I found a similar issue with RVM, not sure if they're related, but I will try a few of the solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032824/cant-install-ruby-under-lion-with-rvm-gcc-issues?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

This is what I get for not reading the entire error, thoroughly. :)

I had llvmgcc42 installed not gcc. I needed GCC for older versions of Ruby.